# Placing strings returned from readdir() into a char **

Tags: c, unix, memory-management

I would like to make an array of strings that hold all of my regular files in the current directory

I have the following

```
DIR *d = opendir(".");
struct dirent *dirent;
struct stat fileStat;
char **files;

while (dirent = readdir(d)) {
    stat(dirent->d_name, &fileStat);

    if (S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode)) {

    }

}

closedir(d);
```

I tried mallocing on the go (in the while loop) each element because the # of regular files in my folder is not predetermined. However, I keep getting segfaults. any ideas?

Comment: Could you include your malloc code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that even the memory for the pointers to the strings is not allocated.

You need to malloc and remalloc `files` to hold the pointers to strings, and then malloc each string separately, or alternatively use strdup which does it for you.

```
size_t files_length = 0;
size_t files_capacity = 16;
char **files = (char**)malloc(files_capacity*sizeof(*files));
if (files == NULL)
    explode();

while (...) {
    if (...) {
        if (files_capacity < files_length + 1) {
            files = (char**)remalloc(files, files_capacity*2*sizeof(*files));
            if (files == NULL) {
                explode();
            }
            files_capacity *= 2;
        }
        files_index = files_length++;
        files[files_index] = strdup(...);
    }
}

// free everything
```

Alternatively you can make `files` just a large array of pointers like `char *files[1024]` and then strdup the filenames into it. But that of course gives you a built in limitation of the number of files you can handle, and costs unnecessary memory if you only have a few files to deal with, although it is only the pointers that cost you extra, not the strings.